# How to set scope properly in Sharpie?

Tags: objective-c, xamarin, binding, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I want to bind some objective-c code using `sharpie`. I have some .h and .m files inside /Users//Documents/binding/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker. My sharpie command looks like this
`sharpie bind -output=InfColorPicker -namespace=InfColorPicker -sdk-iphoneos12.2 -scope Users/<username>/Documents/binding/InfColorPicker/InfColorPicker/*.h`. But the `ApiDefinition.cs`and `Struct.cs` are very huge. I think it has binded all the included framework (coregraphic, foundation etc..). How do I properly set the scope to my .h files.
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you watch [this video](https://youtu.be/NyqxScrnJKw?t=3751) starting at 1:02:31, presented by the Lead of the Xamarin Components team, Jonathan Dick, you will notice that in the generated files, you can delete the unwanted objects that you don't need. You can just keep the stuff that is relevant for your purposes.